# Button can trigger onClick Event?

Tags: android, button, touch

I have a paino keyboard[image: paino keyboard]

Every key is a button.

When I sliding from key1 to key2. the key1 first pressed, and then released. but the key2 can not get pressed.
I have set View.OnTouchListener, when sliding from key1 to key2, only key1 get onTouchEvent, even my finger stay above key2.

But if I move up my finger and move down to key2, key2 will trigger onTouchEvent and onClick Event.

Now, I would like to trigger onClick event when finger stay above key2, no matter user first press key1 or key2.

Answer (score 1):

return true value from Event processing  methods like e.g. onKeyUp, onKeyDown method and rest

Answer (score 0):

If i assume that `onTouchListener` works like `onClickListener` have you tried to define the case that the `button2` is pressed inside the case of `button1` is pressed?
What about using a gesture Scanner?